# Split function vba

Tags: vba

I am currently attempting to take user input and split each bit of input using a comma. Currently I am trying to use -

```
   includer = CStr(InputBox("Do you have any inclusions? Separate words with commas"))
        inclusion = Split(includer, ",", , vbTextCompare)
```

with no luck.

It keeps throwing a 'Type Mismatch' error.

The full code I am attempting to use, for anyone that is interested, is-

```
Option Compare Text

Public Sub Textchecker()
'
' Textchecker
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
Dim Continue As Long
Dim findWhat As String
Dim LastLine As Long
Dim toCopy As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
Dim item As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim sheetIndex As Long
Dim inclusion() As String


sheetIndex = 2

Continue = vbYes
    Do While Continue = vbYes

        findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
        includer = CStr(InputBox("Do you have any inclusions? Separate words with commas"))
        inclusion = Split(includer, ",", , vbTextCompare)

        LastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
        j = 1
    For item = 1 To LastLine
        For Each cell In Range("BY1").Offset(item - 1, 0)
            If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 And InStr(cell.Text, inclusion(x)) <> 0 Then
                toCopy = True

            End If
        Next
        If toCopy = True Then
            Sheets(sheetIndex).Name = UCase(findWhat) + "+" + LCase(inclusion(x))
            Rows(item).Copy Destination:=Sheets(sheetIndex).Rows(j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
        toCopy = False
    Next item
    sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1
    Continue = MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: that will also blow up when your user ESC-out of your `InputBox`

Comment: I have had no issues with it, may I ask why you say that?

Comment: meh, VB must be string-coalescing the null string pointer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Dim inclusion As String
```

to

```
Dim inclusion() As String 'recommended in my opinion
```

or

```
Dim inclusion As variant
```

## Edit

I see your use of inclusion later in the code.  It looks like you need to iterate over your new array.

```
dim x as long 'put this at the top, rename as you'd like.
for x = lbound(inclusion) to ubound(inclusion)
   'do stuff with inclusion(x), i other code here before but I'm not sure that it was right anymore.
next
```

## Edit 2

```
        For item = 1 To LastLine
            If UBound(insulation) >= 0 Then
                'write procedure for when inclusion are present
            Else
                'write 2nd procedure for when inclusions are not present
            End If
        Next item
```

Comment: I will go ahead and give it a try, may I ask why you recommend inclusion() over putting it as a variant? Also, when I change it to an array, it calls errors in the rest of my code.

Comment: I avoid variants when I can.  The errors are from using an array without an index.  See my edit.

Comment: Alright, I went ahead and tried that as well, put the changes into the orginial post. I have it almost working perfectly. Only thing I have left is to handle instances where there is no inclusion statement entered. I am attempting to have it automatically place a comma when there is nothing entered.
I tried -
If inclusion(x) = "" Then inclusion(x) = ","
 but had no luck

Comment: I'm getting lost in your logic a bit it it looks like you don't every iterate over the items in inclusion.  Is that necessary?  As your code is written it'll only ever check the first item in inclusion since x will default to 0.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is the first time I am writing anything this intensive in VBA. I am trying to have it check for all interactions that have the initial keyword and then within those results, find any interactions that include the inclusion statements, take those results and copy them to another sheet, naming that sheet based on the words searched.

Comment: See Edit2, I would break down your problem with new procedures.  One for when there are inclusions and one without.