# How do I split a cell with multiple delimiters in visual basic?

Tags: string, excel, cell, delimiter, vba

I want to use VBA to split the contents of a cell into three separate parts, such as [city], [state] [zip code] are put into three different columns on the same row while leaving the original cell unchanged.

I had thought that split would work, but unfortunately I have encountered some complicating issues, first split seems to only carry over the what's on the left, leaving behind the rest, second, I don't see how I can incorporate two delimiters into a single split.

Any idea how to surmount these issues?

```
    Cells(Row1, ColA).Select
    Location = ActiveCell.Value

    Cells(Row1, ColC) = Split(Location, ",")


    Cells(Row1, ColA).Select
    Cells(Row1, ColD) = Split(Location, " ")

    Cells(Row1, ColA).Select
    Cells(Row1, ColE) = Split(Location, " ")
```

Comment: Try th code below, and see if it works for you

Comment: have you tried the code in the answers you got here ?

Answer (score 0):

`Split()` returns an array of strings, you need to iterate through this array and assign the value of each element to the corresponding cell (take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30175682/6481438)).

Also, you don't need to select cells to assign values to it, you may use:

`Cells(Row,Column).Value = X`

Regarding 2 delimiters, you may do it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680537/6481438).

Answer (score 0):

Use the ***Split***, I use an array in the middle just to store the split String (in case you will want to use it later), it also saves me the time of the iteration.

```
Sub Split_toThree()

Dim lrow                As Long
Dim LastRow             As Long
Dim SplitArr()          As String

' find last row in Column A (where you keep your full string)
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For lrow = 2 To LastRow
    SplitArr() = Split(Cells(lrow, "a"), ",")
    Range("C" & lrow & ":E" & lrow) = SplitArr()
Next lrow

End Sub
```